# ¿Que diferencias hay entre inicializar variables miembro en la declaración y en el constructor?

Tags: java, poo

¿Hay alguna diferencia entre estas dos formas de inicializar los miembros de una clase?

Inicializando las variables en el constructor:

```
public class Clase {

    int valor;
    OtraClase otraClase;

    public Clase() {
        this.valor = 1;
        this.otraClase = new OtraClase();

        // codigo extra aqui... 
    }
}
```

Inicializando las variables en la declaración:

```
public class Clase {

    int valor = 1;
    OtraClase otraClase = new OtraClase();

    public Clase() {
        // codigo extra aqui... 
    }
}
```

Comment: La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora mismo se basa en opiniones y debería ser cerrada. Deberías modificarla para que encaje en las normas del centro de ayuda o borrarla ya que no esta relacionada con lo que se espera en este sitio (no hay ningún problema de programación que arreglar)

Comment: Si hay dos o más formas de hacer algo, ¿todas son igual de buenas? Trato de aprender, no sólo de arreglar lo que esta roto. Quiero saber el porque de las cosas y si una vía es mejor que otra, siempre hay diferencias... puede ser que sólo sea un tema de legibilidad, de escribir menos código, pero también puede haber cuestiones de rendimiento que lleven a evitar futuros problemas con cosas más complejas.

Comment: No es todo pros o todo contras normalmente nunca, algunas veces las cosas simplemente dependen de normas internas de un equipo de desarrollo o de cómo nos gusta a cada uno hacer cada cosa. En cualquiera de esos casos se basa en opiniones, no en certezas, y cualquier respuesta que se dé a tu pregunta no será una verdad absoluta, será simplemente una opinión más. Ese tipo de publicaciones es lo que quiere evitar este sitio y por eso hay normas que se deben observar.

Comment: Esta es una pregunta valida @Awes0meM4n aunque tu no conozcas la respuesta, hay una y esta basada en hechos y puede ponerse una referencia como este por ejemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994218/should-i-instantiate-instance-variables-on-declaration-or-in-the-constructor

Comment: No sé si a nivel de rendimiento habrá una diferencia sustancial... Pero la segunda forma suele ser la preferida por muchos de los compañeros con los que me codeo, y la mía propia, por una sencilla razón: "legibilidad". La segunda forma es mucho más clara y es más fácil de leer, de cara a documentar, permite establecer comentarios de código por cada variable/propiedad, cosa que te resultará útil con algunos IDE.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n no creo que se base en opiniones. En realidad la respuesta es "hacen lo mismo, elige el estilo que más le convenga al equipo". En lo personal, escojo el segundo por la legibilidad y porque, en caso mi clase tenga más de un constructor, inicializo los campos con valores por defecto en un solo lugar. La única razón por la que usaría la primera forma es si un campo se inicializa basado en un método que puede lanzar una excepción.

Comment: Después de leer los comentarios y la respuesta en inglés sigo pensando que "principalmente" se basa en opiniones. Hay razones que van a limitar el uso de una u otra, pero se han puesto dos ejemplos que no son excluyentes: podría dar un valor por defecto que en un constructor en concreto cambie. Por eso sigo pensando que no hay una respuesta absoluta y que se basa en opiniones ya que algunos ponéis: "preferida por muchos compañeros", "se lee mejor", etc... y eso son opiniones. A mi me resulta más legible la primera y no me llevará al huerto si tengo un constructor que cambie.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n el hecho es que **es lo mismo**. Lo demás son opiniones y la respuesta **es necesaria** justamente por eso, para hacer bien esa distinción y erradicar de una vez la duda y las opiniones.

Comment: A mi personalmente me gusta más la primera opción y te doy mis motivos: - Cuando declaras una clase, si ya le estableces valores a las variables internas, estas estableciendo un comportamiento que va a heredar la persona que lo use. - No me gusta establecer valores en los constructores, pero si lo haces te permite tener distintos constructores con distintos valores (siempre y cuando la firma te lo permita). - Y la principal ventaja que veo es que si recuperas el valor de algunas de las propiedades nunca sabrás si ese valor está ahí por que el proceso lo ha puesto o porque la clase lo ha creado

Comment: Creo que la respuesta que tiene ahora mismo esta pregunta es lo que al final tienen este tipo de preguntas. Los que abanderais la causa de que es necesaria una respuesta podríais dar una si estais tan convencidos. Yo si pudiera pasaría todos estos comentarios a un chat para hablar del tema mejor que por aquí, porque sigo sin entender lo que decís. Por favor si algún moderador puede que lo haga ya.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas son totalmente válidas, pero si llegas a tener 2 o más constructores en tu clase puede que iniciar las variables en la declaración te sea mas efectiva. Ahora, también existe una tercera forma de hacerlo con un inicializador de instancia, puedes hacer esto (se ejecutan antes de la llamada al constructor):

```
public class Clase {
    int valor ;
    OtraClase otraClase ;

    {
      valor = 1;
      otraClase = new OtraClase();
    }

    public Clase() {
        // codigo extra aqui... 
    }
}
```